# Creating tags only if no result in ajax with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

When I search for a postal code I don't have in my database, the user can create is own tag and submit but if the code is in my database, 2 results appears.
Let's say the user is looking for Marseille, he writes 13002 and the results would be:
13002
13002 Marseille
And I only want the second result to appear because it's already in my database. This is my code :

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'Select2/select2';
import 'Select2/select2_locale_fr';


$('#postal_code_search_zipcode').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 5,
    maximumInputLength: 5,
    maximumSelectionLength: 1,
    formatNoMatches: function() {
        return '';
    },
    language: 'fr',
    //tags: [],
    createSearchChoice: function (term) {
        return {
            id: $.trim(term),
            text: $.trim(term)
        };
    },
    ajax: {
        cache: false,
        url: $('#postal_code_search_zipcode').data('autocomplete-url'),
        delay: 250,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: params => ({
            q: params || '',
        }),
        processResults: data => ({
            results: Object.keys(data).map(value => ({
                id: value,
                text: data[value]
            }))
        })
    }
});
```